# Tetris - Right side collision flickering issue

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am a student in high school doing a summative project in tetris. Lately I've been having this problem where for certain positions, when my block collides with the RIGHT side of the screen, it sort of 'flickers'. I can't seem to find the reason why it is doing this, and I don't know if the shape is going out of the grid and coming in and being drawn again, I'm not sure and very confused.

So far I've been able to make random blocks spawn once the first one hits the ground, I've been able to do collision with the left side correctly for all my blocks, some stacking and rotation works as well. I've included the main ideas of how I did my code as a lot of it is repeated, so I included 2 examples of each. (2 different rotations, 2 ways shown of how I drew the block, etc.)

I'm really stuck so if someone could help that would be amazing, Thank you.

```
    import pygame
    import colors
    import random

    class Shape:

        def __init__ (self, x, y, shape1, shape2, shape3, shape4, shapeType):
            self.shape1 = shape1
            self.shape2 = shape2
            self.shape3 = shape3
            self.shape4 = shape4
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.lasty = 0
            self.direction = 0
            self.collided = False
            self.fc = 0
            self.shapeType = shapeType

        def draw (self, screen):
            self.lasty = self.y
            self.fc += 1
            if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_DOWN] and self.fc >= 5:
                self.fc = 0
                self.y += 39
            elif self.fc >= 90:
                self.fc = 0
                self.y += 39

            if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_RIGHT] and self.fc >= 5:
                self.fc = 0
                self.x += 39


            elif self.fc >= 90:
                self.fc = 0
                self.x += 39

            ## When the block collides with the bottom of the grid
            if self.y >= 778:
                self.y = 0

## I USE 'DIRECTION' TO REPRESENT THE DIFFERENT ROTATED POSITIONS -- ONLY 1 IS SHOWN BELOW BUT I HAVE (0-3 DIRECTIONS) = 4 DIFFERENT ROTATIONS
            if self.direction == 0: # if the shape is in the first position
                for y in range(len(self.shape1)): # RUNS A LOOP THAT GETS THE LENGTH OF THE SHAPE IN THE FIRST POSITION
                    for x in range(len(self.shape1[y])):
                        if self.shape1[y][x] == 1 and not self.collided:
                            if (self.y + 39*y) + 39 > 780: # CHECKS THAT THE SHAPE IS NOT GOING PASSED THE RIGHT SIDE OF THE GRID
                                self.collided = True
                            if (self.x + (39*x)) >= 739:
                                self.x = 740-(39*x)-39
                            for blok in blocks: ## stacking the blocks and checking if the block collides with the other blocks
                                if self.x + (39*x) == blok.x and self.y + (39*y) == blok.y:
                                    self.collided = True
                            pygame.draw.rect(screen, colors.lightBlue,(self.x + (39*x), self.y + (39*y), 39,39))

            elif self.direction == 1: # WHEN THE SHAPE IS IN THE SECOND ROTATION
                for y in range(len(self.shape2)):
                    for x in range(len(self.shape2[y])):
                        if self.shape2[y][x] == 1 and not self.collided:
                            if(self.y + 39*y) + 39 > 780:
                                self.collided = True
                            if (self.x + (39*x)) >= 739:
                                self.x = 740-(39*x)-39
                            for blok in blocks:
                                if self.x + (39*x) == blok.x and self.y + (39*y) == blok.y:
                                    self.collided = True
                            pygame.draw.rect(screen, colors.lightBlue,(self.x + (39*x), self.y + (39*y), 39,39))

            if self.collided == True:
                self.y = self.lasty
                if self.direction == 0:
                    for y in range(len(self.shape1)):
                        for x in range(len(self.shape1[y])):
                            if self.shape1[y][x] == 1:
                                blocks.append(Block(self.x + (39 * x), self.y + (39 * y)))

                elif self.direction == 1:
                    for y in range(len(self.shape2)):
                        for x in range(len(self.shape2[y])):
                            if self.shape2[y][x] == 1:
                                blocks.append(Block(self.x + (39 * x), self.y + (39 * y)))

    class Block:
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y

        def draw(self, screen):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, colors.lightBlue, (self.x, self.y, 39, 39))

    blocks = []
    ## EXAMPLE OF HOW EACH SHAPE IS DRAWN

    ## L SHAPE
    b = Shape(350,0, [[1,1],[0,1],[0,1]], [[0,0,1],[1,1,1]], [[1,0,],[1,0], [1,1]], [[1,1,1],[1,0,0]],"L SHAPE")

    ## Z SHAPE
    ##b = Shape(300,300, [[0,1],[1,1],[1,0]], [[1,1],[0,1,1]], [[0,1],[1,1],[1,0]], [[1,1],[0,1,1]])

# FUNCTION FOR THE GRID
    def drawGrid(_x, _y, screen,width,height, columns,rows ):
        for y in range(0, rows+1):
            for x in range(0, columns+1):
                screen.fill(colors.grey, [(x*(width/columns))+_x, _y, 1, height])
            screen.fill(colors.grey, [_x, (y*(height/rows))+_y, width, 1])

    def drawGame(screen, scene): # UPDATING DRAW FUNCTION
        global b
        for evn in pygame.event.get():
            if evn.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()
                return scene, True

            elif evn.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: 
                if evn.key == pygame.K_UP: # IF THE UP ARROW KEY IS PRESSED, CHANGE THE ROTATION OF THE SHAPE
                    b.direction += 1
                    if b.direction == 4: # IF THE DIRECTION EQUALS 4 RESET TO THE FIRST POSITION
                        b.direction = 0
        screen.fill(colors.black)

    ## ACCELERATES THE BLOCK DOWNWARDS

        drawGrid(350, 0, screen, 390, 780, 10, 20)
        if not b.collided:
            b.draw(screen)
        else:  # CHECKS WHICH VALUE OUT OF (0-6) IS RECEIVED TO CHOOSE THE RANDOM SHAPE
            i = random.randint(0,6)  
            if i == 0: 
                ## L shape
                b = Shape(350,0, [[1,1],[0,1],[0,1]], [[0,0,1],[1,1,1]], [[1,0,],[1,0], [1,1]], [[1,1,1],[1,0,0]],"L SHAPE")

            elif i == 5:
                ## Z Shape
                b = Shape(350, 0, [[0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0]], [[1, 1], [0, 1, 1]], [[0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0]],
                      [[1, 1], [0, 1, 1]],"Z SHAPE")

        for i in blocks: # RUNS THE LOOP TO DRAW THE SHAPE
            i.draw(screen) #  DRAWS THE VALUE OF 'i' ONTO THE SCREEN

        pygame.display.flip()
        return scene, False
```

Comment: You're checking if the block has collided, but drawing it anyway, which means that sometimes it will be drawn and then put back in the old position. Try to move the line `pygame.draw.rect(screen, colors.lightBlue,(self.x + (39*x), self.y + (39*y), 39,39))` after the `if self.collided == True`. Also, a lot of code is duplicated, I suggest you move that code to functions to make it easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I was drawing some of the rectangles in the draw loop before some of them were checked for collision with the wall.